# Jquery Tablesorter execution

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am new to jquery and I have downloaded the jquery tablesorter plugin and started using is. However, the jquery is not being applied and I dont understand why.
here is my jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5wcjd2fc/2/

```
<title>Population Change from 2000 to 2010</title>
<meta  charset="utf-8" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.12.2.min.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.tablesorter.min"> </script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme.grey.css">
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#population").tablesorter({
      theme: "grey",
      widgets: ['zebra']
    });   
</script>
<body>
<h1>Population Change from 2000 to 2010</h1>
<table id="population" class="tablesorter">
```

Answer (score 0):

Tablesorter tables need to contain thead and tbody tags. Ensure that your headers are within thead and that your sortable content is in tbody.

Everything else looks fine. Obviously, make sure your script files are being imported successfully. Typing $ in the developer console should be enough to know if jQuery is available.

Comment: Also, I'm unfamiliar with the "widgets" of tablesorter, but make sure you don't need to import another script file for that to work. Ensure no javascript errors exist on your page.